# Showing different value in image with different color in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working in Matlab 2009. I have a array (say test) like:

```
 0    0    0     0
 1.2 1.2  1.4  1.6
 1.2 1.3  1.3  1.7
```

This array actually represents a Image after performing few operations.

I want the same values to be represented in one color. Say all pixels corresponding to value 1.2 should be represented in red color (while using `imshow` function).

How can this be done? Please help

Comment: What do you want all the values that aren't 1.2 to be represented as?

Comment: Similar values to be represented in one color. So values 1.3's in other color 1.4's in other than 1.2 and 1.3 and so on

Comment: `imshow` does that by default...?

Comment: Perhaps you want the `lines` [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)? i.e. after `imshow` type `imshow('lines')`

Comment: map the maximum and minimum numbers to 0 and 255 respectively. Then you will have 256bit colors images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `imagesc` will assign one color per value.

The code

```
a=[ 0    0    0     0 
    1.2 1.2  1.4  1.6
    1.2 1.3  1.3  1.7];

imagesc(a);
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: To add some minor information to this answer: use `colormap` to change the colors if you want to. By default, colors are taken into `colormap(jet(64))`, but you can change it after the call of `imagesc` (I prefer this one to `imshow`).